# AJAX post data is null in controller mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I try to send a JSON object back to the server. This is my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/NewService',
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(props),
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("FAIL: " + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("SUCCES");
    }
});
```

The evaluation of `JSON.stringify(props)` in the browser's debugger is

`"[{"name":"firstName","value":"firstValue"}]"`

This is the method in the controller which is being called:

```
[HttpPost]
public void NewService(dynamic json)
{
    Response.Write(json);
}
```

The problem I have is that always the `json` variable from above is an empty object.
The `success` function gets called but when I debug the `json` var is displayed as empty.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.
Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't think you can bind to a dynamic type the way you're trying to. You can try to create a class that maps your data, something like:

```
public class Content
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewService(Content[] data)
{
    // sweet !
}
```

And in your js like Olaf Dietsche said you need to specify your `contentType`:

```
var props = [
    { "Name": "firstName", "Value": "firstValue" }, 
    { "Name": "secondName", "Value": "secondValue" }
];

$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/NewService',
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: true,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(props),
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("FAIL: " + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("SUCCESS!");
    }
});
```

Comment: `contentType: "application/json",` fixed my problem... thank you!

Answer (score 9):

According to [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), the default content type is is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If you want to send the data as JSON, you must change this to

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/NewService',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    ...
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Use the following code to solve this problem

Ajax Call

> ```
>        function SaveDate() {
>         var obj = {};
>         obj.ID = '10';
>         obj.Name = 'Shafiullah';
>
>         $.ajax({
>             url: '/Home/GetData',
>             dataType: "json",
>             type: "Post",
>             contentType: 'application/json',
>             data: JSON.stringify({ ID: obj.ID, Name: obj.Name }),
>             async: true,
>             processData: false,
>             cache: false,
>             success: function (data) {
>                 alert(data.id + ' , ' + data.name);
>             },
>             error: function (xhr) {
>                 alert('error');
>             }
>         });
>     }
> ```

My controller action method

> ```
>         [HttpPost]
>         public IActionResult GetData([FromBody] Employee employee)
>         {
>             return Json(employee);
>         }
> ```

Comment: This 5 year old already has an upvoted, accepted answer. Can you add some text to your answer explaining what this improves upon the accepted answer?

Comment: I have no much time, but this is work correctly just use this